# Outlook Add-in for Office 365 is not being activated by default

Tags: api, office365, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

We have created an Outlook add-in and installed it on Office365 account but every time when I login and after I perform any action I have to manually click on add-in to activate. I do not want this.  I want to run the add-in in background so it will active  once I login to my office365 outlook account and it should remain active by default is there any way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This compose scenario for the mail add-in  need the users to active the add-in. However the latest feature named add-in command enable the add-in has placed new buttons on the command ribbon. So users are not required to active the add-in first to make it work, then can just click the command on the ribbon. Here is an figure for your reference:
[image]

However, current it only work for the Outlook 2016.

If you were find a solution for all the client, you may consider using transport rules or journaling instead of the mail add-in. You can refer to the link below for more detail:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/01/28/3409250.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the add-in model is designed such that users have to manually run the add-ins. Running automatically is a new feature request, which other developers have asked for as well in our User Voice page, please feel free to upvote it here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/10770030-autorun-outlook-add-ins.